# if ($obj->hashes > $minimal_withdraw) do { ); $response but response is too much

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, do-while

everytime that there are 256 hashes available there should be added 1 credits to the user account.
but it keeps looping , it add's more credits to the user account then there are actually hashes been made...

how can i fix this?

this is where i am :

```
<?php //second one ,much  loops to 
$x = $obj->hashes; 
$minimal_withdraw = "255";

if ($obj->hashes > $minimal_withdraw)
do {
$DBcon->query("UPDATE promotion_users SET credits=credits+1 WHERE username='$session'");
$response = file_get_contents("https://webminepool.com/api/PK_bzM7NcgKs2c4pkidkiNpp/withdraw/" . $userRow[username] . "/" . $minimal_withdraw);
$x = $obj->hashes;
} while ($x >= $minimal_withdraw)  ;

?>
```

This is what i also try'd :

```
<?php  // first one
//$minimal_withdraw = "256";
//if ($obj->hashes > $minimal_withdraw) { $DBcon->query("UPDATE * FROM promotion_users SET credits=credits + 1 WHERE username=='$session'");
//$response = file_get_contents("https://webminepool.com/api/PK_bzM7NcgKs2c4pkidkiNpp/withdraw/" . //$userRow[username] . "/" . $minimal_withdraw); }
?>
```

And this one (didnt even load):

```
<?php //didnt load page
//$x = $obj->hashes; 
//$minimal_withdraw = "256";

//foreach ($x >= $minimal_withdraw) {
//$DBcon->query("UPDATE promotion_users SET credits=credits+1 WHERE username='$session'");
//$response = file_get_contents("https://webminepool.com/api/PK_bzM7NcgKs2c4pkidkiNpp/withdraw/" . //$userRow[username] . "/" . $minimal_withdraw);
//} ?>
```